# Formula for average time in Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a model like:

```
  A     B     C
A 0.80  0.10  0.10
B 0.20  0.75  0.05
C 0.10  0.10  0.80
```

How do I get the average time from B to A? I understand that there's a formula:

$$
m_{ij}=1+\sum_{k\neq j}p_{ik}m_{kj}
$$

But I'm not sure what to do with the recursion. Can k=i?

I started with

$ m_{BA} = 1 + p_{BC} m_{CA} $

$ m_{CA} = 1 + p_{CB} m_{BA} $

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Yes, the summation is over all $k \neq j$; so in particular, we have to consider $k=i$ (whenever $i \neq j$).

---

For simplicity of notation, let's identify

$$A \longleftrightarrow 1 \qquad B \longleftrightarrow 2 \qquad C \longleftrightarrow 3.$$

Then the mentioned formula gives

$$m_{21} = 1+ p_{22} m_{21} + p_{23} m_{31} = 1+ \frac{3}{4} m_{21} + \frac{1}{20} m_{31} \tag{1}$$

and

$$m_{31} = 1+ p_{32} m_{21} + p_{33} m_{31} = 1+ \frac{1}{10} m_{21} + \frac{4}{5} m_{31} \tag{2}$$

Equation $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{4} m_{21} = 1+ \frac{1}{20} m_{31} \tag{1'}$$

and equation $(2)$ is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{5} m_{31} = 1+ \frac{1}{10} m_{21} \tag{2'}$$

i.e. we have to solve a system of linear equations (2 equations, 2 unknowns). It is not difficult to see that

$$m_{21} = \frac{50}{9} \qquad \quad m_{31} = \frac{70}{9}.$$